# View port resize based on user selection

Tags: angularjs, html, css

Basically I have an angular project that is based on bootstrap 3 for media queries resize.

What I intend to do is allow user to change between desktop mode (laptop full screen width) or mobile mode (media width < 667px).

I have see a lot of theme preview sites have this feature. As it is quite a common feature, I expect that it can be done this way but not sure how it could be implemented exactly.

**Note**: I am not expecting to change any part of existing CSS.

My opinion on how to implement this.

```
<html ng-viewport="deviceWidth">
    <button ng-click="changeDeviceWidth()">
</html>

// initial
$scope.deviceWidth = getDeviceWidthFunction();
$scope.changeDeviceWidth = function (deviceWidth) {
    $scope.deviceWidth = deviceWidth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First: Give id to you viewport meta

```
    <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Second: Create selector buttons

```
    <div id="selecter">
    <button onclick="toDesktop()"> Desktop</button>
    <button onclick="toTablet()"> Tablet</button>
    <button onclick="toMobile()"> Mobile</button>
    </div>
```

Third: Add iframe as content viewer

```
            <iframe id="mycontent" src="http://www.majali.net"></iframe>
```

Fourth: Add JS functions to set viewport,content width and height

```
         <script>
            function toDesktop() {
                document.getElementById("viewport").setAttribute("content", "width=1200");
                document.getElementById("mycontent").style.width='100%';
                document.getElementById("mycontent").style.height='600px';                  
            }

            function toMobile() {
                document.getElementById("viewport").setAttribute("content", "width=340");
                document.getElementById("mycontent").style.width='320px';
                document.getElementById("mycontent").style.height='480px';
            }       

            function toTablet() {
                document.getElementById("viewport").setAttribute("content", "width=767");
                document.getElementById("mycontent").style.width='767px';
                document.getElementById("mycontent").style.height='600px';
            }                           
        </script>
```